# Tippy.js is not on top of Flickity slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltip, flickity

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
The first image is as it is in my project, it is not on the slide elements. It gets cut off by the div, I believe that flickity has to do with it.

Flickit Docs:https://flickity.metafizzy.co/

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
Here's another case where I put the tippy, not on a slide, and it displays the information correctly

Tippy.js Docs:https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/

What I've tried to do:
I tried to set the position of tippy.js elements with absolute to be on top of flickity, but for some reason this doesn't work. And he continues with the tooltip under the box.

How could I solve this?
Code:

```
<style>
    .carousel {
  background: #EEE;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 28%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #8C8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  counter-increment: carousel-cell;
}

.carousel-cell.is-selected {
  background: #ED2;
}

/* cell number */
.carousel-cell:before {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: counter(carousel-cell);
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
<div  id="lancamentosCarousel" class="recommended"  >
    <div id="lancamentos" class="box">
        <div class="head">
            <a href="#" onclick="toggleTorrents(0); return false;"><strong>Últimos torrents lançados</strong></a>
            | <a href="#" onclick="toggleTorrents(1); return false;"><strong>Últimos filmes</strong></a>
            | <a href="#" onclick="toggleTorrents(2); return false;"><strong>Últimas séries</strong></a>
            <span style="float: right;"><a href="#" onclick="toggleAll(); return false;" >Toggle</a></span>
        </div>
                <!-- Flickity HTML init -->
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="hidden" id="tooltip_10033">
                <div class="movie-tooltip__title-row">
                    <a class="movie-tooltip__title" href="torrents.php?id=10033">
                        Final Exam          </a>
                    <span class="movie-tooltip__year">[1981]
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-tooltip__director-list">por 
                    <a class="movie-tooltip__director" href="https://www.imdb.com/find?q=Jimmy Huston">Jimmy Huston         </a>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-tooltip__ratings">
                    <div class="movie-tooltip__rating-container">
                        <span class="cover-movie-list__movie__rating">
                            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.imdb.com/title/
                                tt0082378/" rel="noreferrer">IMDb
                            </a>: 
                            4.7             </span>
                        <span class="cover-movie-list__movie__rating">
                            <a target="_blank">Votos TMDb
                            </a>: 
                            48              </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-tooltip__tags tagstooltip">
                                <a id="urlTorrent" href="torrents.php?taglist=
                        horror" class="movie-tooltip__tag">
                        horror          </a>
                            
                                <a id="urlTorrent" href="torrents.php?taglist=
                        thriller" class="movie-tooltip__tag">
                        thriller            </a>
                            
                            </div>
                        <div class="movie-tooltip__trailer" onclick="youtubeShowPopup('tA4niBgNOWE',true);">
                    <img class="movie-tooltip__trailer__image" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/tA4niBgNOWE/default.jpg">
                        <img class="movie-tooltip__trailer__play" src="static/common/symbols/play.png">
                </div>
                        <div class="movie-tooltip__synopsis">
                    <p style="padding-top: 10px"><strong>Sinopse: </strong>Em "A Hora das Sombras - Exame Final", um psicopata desconhecido invade os jardins da universidade e, com sua insaciável sede de destruição, mata violentamente pessoas inocentes. A tranqüilidade do campus acabou com a sua chegada. Agora o pânico tomou conta dos jovens estudantes.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="movie-tooltip__torrents">
                    <div style="padding-top: 10px">
                        <strong>Formato</strong>: MKV           </div>
                    <div>
                        <strong>Qualidade</strong>: BRRip           </div>
                    <div>
                        <strong>Tamanho</strong>: 4 GB          </div>
                            </div>
                <div class="movie-tooltip__action-row">
                    <span class="movie-tooltip__bookmark">
                        <a href="#" onclick="Bookmark('torrent', 10033, 'Remover Favorito'); return false;">Favoritar</a>
                    </span>
            </div>
    </div>
          <div class="carousel-cell" id="torrentid_10033">
                      <script>
                      var template_10033 = document.getElementById('tooltip_10033');
                      tippy('#torrentid_10033', {
                        content:  template_10033.innerHTML,
                        arrow: true,
                        placement: 'right',
                        interactive: true,
                        allowHTML: true,
                      });
                    </script>   
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
          <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
          <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
          <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
          <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
          <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
          <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
          <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
          <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
          <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O problema estava no overflow.

Comment: I try to edit z-index element in tippy.js options, but doesn't work.

Comment: I changed the overflow value in .flickity-viewport.  I'm almost done.But the expected result has not yet been achieved.